# Can't load Node.js images in my React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I have some images stored in my Node.js server and would like to render them in my React app. I have prepared the static folder and can access the image in my browser thanks to this configuration, but I can't load it on my React file.

**React Component:**

All of these `data` attributes load without a problem, only the image doesn't load. If I access the URL in `data.aa[0].main_image_url` on the browser (that is `http://localhost:5001/kit-images/1689941209198--Elysium.jpg`) it displays the image without an issue.

```
function SerumRowNoProviders() {

  const { data } = useContext(kitsDataContext);

  return (
    
      <div className="small-container">
        <h1>SERUM PRESETS</h1>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-3 text-center">
            <img src={data.aa[0].main_image_url} alt="Product 1" />
            <div>{data.aa[0].name}</div>
            <div>{data.aa[0].price}</div>
            <AddToCart />
          </div>
        </div>
        {/*takes user to page with all avaliable kits */}
        <h1><button type="button" id="show-more" className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg">BROWSE ALL</button></h1>
      </div>
  );
}
```

I tried loading it with `<img src="http://localhost:5001/kit-images/1689941209198--Elysium.jpg" alt="Product 1" />` too, but it also doesn't work

**Node.js:**

Here's how I set up the static folder.

```
app.use("/kit-images", express.static(__dirname + "/src/serum-presets"));
```

If I delete this line, the image becomes inaccessible even on the browser so that's an indication that this is working.

Comment: what does the `data.aa[0].main_image_url` contain exactly, is there any error in browser dev tools

Comment: It contains this exact URL: `http://localhost:5001/kit-images/1689941209198--Elysium.jpg`

and this URL is valid and working on the browser (just not on my React app). No, there is no error on my React page itself, but, when I open the URL I just showed you, the image loads but with a warning: `Content-Security-Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“script-src”).`

Comment: well, it's hard to tell... truly, that's the value, with the port number and all..? are you sure it isn't just `1689941209198--Elysium.jpg`..? did you try `<img src="kit-images/1689941209198--Elysium.jpg" alt="Product 1" />`

Comment: Yes, I am sure, that's the value in my Mongo database. I can't do `<img src="kit-images/1689941209198--Elysium.jpg" alt="Product 1" />` because the image is on my server folder and the only way to access it is using the URL with the correct port and route.

Comment: can't tell.. try some similar questions: [React: Image uploaded from node js backend is not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67694364/react-image-uploaded-from-node-js-backend-is-not-rendering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. The issue was related to CORS. I've set up CORS in the node.js code (this is only meant for development, do not set up CORS like this in production!):

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

But that still wasn't working so I had to set the `crossorigin` to "anonymous" in all `<img>` tags:

```
<img crossorigin="anonymous" src="http://localhost:5001/kit-images/1689941209198--Elysium.jpg" alt="Product 1" />
```

And done. The lack of error messages is what made me make this question, if the browser (Firefox) had specified that this was a CORS related issue this would have been so much easier to fix.